# What does /=/ mean in Netezza?

Tags: netezza

I am converting some views from Netezza into another DBMS.

I keep running into this operator `/=/`, which I imagine is some sort of equality operator.

However, I have searched this site [and the official docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_functions_expressions_operators.html), but I cannot find a definition of how this operator works.

What does `/=/` mean in Netezza?

**EDIT:**
I am seeing it in `case` statements.

Here is an example:

```sql
CASE WHEN (A_TABLE.A_COL /=/ 'ONE'::VARCHAR) THEN 'ONE'::VARCHAR 
WHEN (A_TABLE.A_COL /=/ 'TWO'::VARCHAR) THEN 'TWO'::VARCHAR 
WHEN (A_TABLE.A_COL /=/ 'THREE'::VARCHAR) THEN 'THREE'::VARCHAR 
WHEN (A_TABLE.A_COL /=/ 'FOUR'::VARCHAR) THEN 'FOUR'::VARCHAR 
ELSE 'OTHER'::VARCHAR END
```

Comment: Can you post a full line of code with that operator?

Comment: Example added, thanks!

Comment: Is it only in case statements? Are there any other values of `A_COL` that aren't ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR?

Comment: It appears to only be in case statements. I don't have access to the data yet, just an empty DDL. Will post more info as I find it though.

Comment: Yeah I can't find that operator in any documentation. My only thought is that it might be comparing value and type, but I can't find documentation to support that

Answer (score 4):

It is a quite powerful feature, often used in JOIN statements and as here in CASE.
Its an operator that tells the database to match NULL in one value to NULL in another. Normally all functions and operators return NULL if one of the arguments is NULL, and since NULL is not TRUE you will not find a match.

This whole tri-state logic surrounding NULL can be quite confusing at times and has clearly been invented in the wrinkled minds of mathematicians, but this special /=/ operator has a behavior that is quite easy to wrap you brain around.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I am unable to find this information in any official documents. Any idea how I might search for it? Searching for the operator itself doesn't seem to work. Thanks for posting!

Comment: I’ve spend 15 minutes googling but /=/ is more or less being disregarded by google... I’ll ask a colleague next time I see him...

Comment: If you get the query plan you would see how the join statement gets translated for `select * from A join B on (A.COL=B.COL or (A.COL ISNULL and B.COL ISNULL))` to ---> `spu HashJoinNode  numSlicesEst=1
                    -- (TBL_B.COL /=/ TBL_A.COL)`

Comment: Interesting, I didn’t know it did a rewrite TO /=/ in the plan. I guess that makes perfect sense from a performance perspective since I suspect it to be implemented in the FPGAs